# I am new to xaml and have questions about stackpanel and adding things to them

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls, stackpanel

My code on the xaml looks something like this

```
   </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Updates Avalable"></Label>

        <Button Name="btnUpdate" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseDoubleClick="btnUpdate_MouseDoubleClick" >Check For Available Updates</Button>
        <StackPanel Name="controlHolder" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Then i create a custom control and try adding it to the stackPanel like this

```
            File_Type_Control_Green ftcg = ftc.GeneratefileTypeControl("file", "hello", "3mb", "someurl", "2-3-4");
        controlHolder.Children.Add(ftcg);
```

However, when i do that it literally puts it inside the button.

In windows forms you can just add controls to panel no problem but it seems to be a big problem in wpf.  I don't know how to go about fixing this.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

main goal is to add the new controls dynamically to the stack panel.  I haven't done it yet, but i will add xy locations to space the controls out properly assuming you can do that like in panel.

Thanks!

Comment: You had both Button and StackPanel filling up the the same grid column and row so you can't visually tell them apart, even that the UserControl is a children of the StackPanel. Place them in a different grid cell or set a background color on the stackpanel so you can see where your UserControl is.

Comment: ............................ so it's one of those days is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had both Button and StackPanel filling up the same grid cell(Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"). The StackPanel has a higher Z-Index but it has transparent background by default, and you may not visually tell them apart as they overlaps. Perhaps you can wrap both your Button and StackPanel into a another StackPanel.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Updates Avalable"></Label>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Name="btnUpdate" />
        <StackPanel Name="controlHolder" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thank you.  it's one of those days where I overlook the obvious again lmao